# Dynamically generate radio group from json

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, radio-group

I'm building a ballot app and I want to dynamically generate a radio group based on a list of candidates in an object. The object looks like this.

```js
{
  "districtAttorney": [{
      "name": "Candidate1",
      "politics": "Dem-District 21",
      "img": "./Candidates/uncleruckus.jpg"
    },
    {
      "name": "Candidate2",
      "politics": "Dem-District 21",
      "img": "./Candidates/uncleruckus.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to generate a radio group that looks like this

```
<div onChange={this.onChangeValue}>
            <input type="radio" value="Candidate1" name="gender" /> Male
            <input type="radio" value="Candidate2" name="gender" /> Female
            <input type="radio" value="Candidate3" name="gender" /> Other
</div>
```

How would I go about this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest something like this:

```
const obj = result.obj //or whatever your object name is
return (
<div onChange={this.onChangeValue}>
    {obj.districtAttorney.map((cand, ind) => (
       <label>
         <input type="radio" value={cand.name} name="gender" />
         <span>{cand.name}</span>
       </lable>
    }
</div>
```

Within the map function you can use all data from the json object

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I want to add a label to the radio but everytime I add text after the <input/> tag I get an error. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I edited my answer so you can wee how to add a label to name the radio button